# JS fadeIn/fadeOut display trouble

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make Skroll to Top button with simple JS effects, but I am stuck at one place. When I click on button it `fades Out` (but it should not), then the scroll is going to the top, my button `fades In` and instantly `fades Out`.

I wanted to get such effect:
I click on the button, the page scrolls to top, button `fades Out`.

This is my code, and I can't find out where is an error.

```
$(function() {

            $(window).scroll(function() {

                if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {

                    $('.page_up').fadeIn();

                } else {

                    $('.page_up').fadeOut();

                }

            });

            $('.page_up').click(function() {

                $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);

            });

        });



.page_up{
    display: none;
    background-image: url("images/1c.png");
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;

}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="page_up"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove anchor `<a href="#">` leaving `<div class="page_up"></div>` alone or return false in `$('.page_up').click()` to fix this

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('.page_up').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.page_up').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $('.page_up').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="page_up"></div></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! Both methods helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fadeOut` after the animation ended:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('.page_up').fadeIn();
        }

    });

    $(".page_up").on('click', function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800, function () {
            $(".page_up").fadeOut()
        });
    })

});
```